# How to use pairwise data to cluster users into group?

Tags: clustering, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

I have a table_1 shows the phone call history, with two columns 'ID_1' and 'ID_2' (id1 calls id2), how can I find the clusters where each user in the cluster in the calls with at least 2 other people within the same cluster?

| ID_1 | ID_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | A |
| A | D |
| D | B |
| E | F |
| F | G |

Based on above table (simple version), expected result to find only 1 cluster with users as A,B,C,D because each of them calls >= 2 people in the same group, while E,F,G not yet form this cluster

Expected result:
Cluster 1 = {A,B,C,D}

Can SQL solve it or we need ML clustering model?